# Protractor Keyword Driven Framework : Printing results to excel

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, protractor, ui-automation

I am developing UI automation framework for an angular application and hence I am using protractor in typescript. I am following a keyword driven approach wherein I specify test case name, action keyword in the excel. Currently,I am reading the excel through 'ts-xlsx' package of npm. 
I am unable to print the result of an action in the excel. 
Any advice on how to achieve the same using any other package or technique.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have used this node package for reading excel files, but you can also write to an excel file - xlsx

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

One problem I had was that when I installed this package globally it was not working, guessing some issue with my setup, but it works when i installed it without global option.

Comment: Hey @Grasshopper, I am using that too. But I am unable to find, how to write to a specific cell that corresponds to a particular row. I guess it only allows writing an entire workbook into an excel and not writing into an individual cell.

Comment: @AYa I think you are right about the write part regarding specific cell edits. Have a look at this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-xlsx. Seems ideal for your requirements...